# How to create a two dimensional list using for loop in Scala?

Tags: scala

If I write the following code in scala I get one dimensional list, as such:

```
scala> for (a <- (1 to 2).toList; b <- (1 to 3).toList) yield (a, b)

res1 = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3))
```

But I'm expecting :-

```
List(List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3)), List((2,1), (2,2), (2,3)))
```

Is it possible to do this using a for loop in scala or is some kind of other construct needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in 2 for comprehensions:

```
for (n <- (1 to 4).toList) yield (for (m <- ('a' to 'c').toList) yield (n, m))
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer, I would like to point out that since in scala `for/yield` is not really _"iterating"_, as the name may suggest to newcomers _(specially for people coming from an **OOP/Imperative** background)_, and is just [syntactic sugar](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) for calls to `map`, `flatMap` & `filter`, @Tom's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `map`

`(1 to 4).toList.map(n => ('a' to 'c').toList.map(m => (n, m)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
{for (i <- 1 to 2; j <- 1 to 3) yield (i,j)}.grouped(3).toList
```

You get a `List` of `Vector`, but that's fine, `Vector` is usually preferred in most circumstances. Fast random access, append, prepend, and updates. You can forgo converting `toList` until the end. If you are OK with `Vector` Tom's answer is really good and you can just refactor down to:

```
(1 to 4).map(n => ('a' to 'c').map(m => (n, m)))
```